# Removing front panel to install new stereo? (Toyota Levin 97)

Tags: toyota, audio, installation

I'm thinking of buying a new stereo for my 1997 Toyota Levin and I was wondering if anyone knew how to take the front panel off so as to get to the old stereo?.

Comment: For anyone whose looking for this its pretty simple. get a flat screw driver and run and pry open the edge of the plastic panel that goes around your air conditioning controls and stereo unit. As you do this it will snap out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in your comment, typically they are one of the following:

- Have tabs that require you to use a flat tool (ie screwdriver) to pop them out
- Have small push in plastic pieces that surround a screw hole. Pop the plastic piece out, then unscrew the panel
- Hidden screws somewhere.

You may find that you have to remove a surrounding panel via the screwdriver method to get to the screws that hold in a neighboring piece.